# ¿Location manager Android? Experiencias

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

He desarrollado una aplicación Gps que envía información a Mysql cada 10 seg atraves de locationmanager. ¿Según su experiencia hasta cuanto es posible disminuir este tiempo?

Comment: Para optimizar Mirate google play services su api de geolocalización.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesante pregunta, al usar [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) tienes dos variables importantes que son `minDistance` que es el mínimo intervalo en el cual se obtienen las notificaciones y `minTime` que es el mínimo intervalo de tiempo para las notificaciones.

Este es un ejemplo, defino lecturas cada 10 minutos (60,000 milisegundos) y cada 10 metros:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, this.locationListener);
```

Como optimizar, depende del requerimiento de tu aplicación, debes tomar en cuenta que si requieres de más muestras, o sea menos distancia y menos tiempo para obtener las lecturas, el consumo de batería es indirectamente proporcional.

Te recomiendo revisar:
**[Location Strategies.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)** (ingles).

Es importante que ahora implementes **[FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)** en lugar de `LocationManager`,  ya que esta clase optimizada para esta tarea y un punto muy importante es que crea un cache donde almacena las lecturas que son usadas por todas las aplicaciones que lo requieran, a diferencia de `LocationManager` que por cada aplicación se genera un proceso de obtención de localización lo cual es costoso para la aplicación.

bye bye [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)...

Comment: La aplicación utiliza una tarea asíncrona que además de enviar lat,lon también leé información del mysql, actualmente la tengo 10segundos 0 metros voy hacer pruebas con 5 segundo 0 metros y os cuento mi experiencia. Implementare FusedLocationProviderApi gracias por la recomendación

Answer (score 0):

Empece probando con 1 segundo 0 metros, todo iba bien hasta que llevaba 5km el servidor empezó a saturarse y recibía los mensajes tardíamente, cambie luego a 5seg 0 metros y el servidor ha estado  estable he recorrido 20km de prueba y no se ha retrasado ninguna muestra.
`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this.locationListener);`

Conclusión la velocidad de transferencia suele variar constantemente debido a que el movil se conecta y se desconecta de una antena  a otra. Como el lapso de tiempo es tan corto empieza a enviar los mensajes tardíamente.